# Regex for search upper letters/words?

Tags: php, regex

I've got string like `"X los(2) - XYZ tres"`

How I can find all upper case letters and words and replace them with random numbers?

From first string I should get `"2 los(2) - 6 tres"` or `"9 los(2) - 5 tres"`

I mean that one UPPER word should becomes one single digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd do it.

Use a regex to find groups of uppercase characters and replace them with a random digit between `0` and `9` (all single digits in a decimal system).

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/[A-Z]+/', function() {
     return rand(0, 9);
}, $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WLf1e2).

Comment: Or, for once, a legitimate and safe use of the `e` modifier: `preg_replace('/[A-Z]+/e', "rand(0,9)", $str);`

Comment: @DaveRandom Yeah, I guess the `e` flag is safe if none of the capturing groups are inserted into the code :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to find uppercase letters and replace them with a random number.

```
$text = "X los(2) - XYZ tres";

// the callback function
function replace_with_random($matches)
{
    return rand(0,9);
}

//perform the replacement
$text= preg_replace_callback(
            "/[A-Z]+/",
            "replace_with_random",
            $text);
```

The callback can inspect the matched text to perform more elaborate replacements than something random - you would find that match in `$matches[0]`

Answer (score 1):

To be unicode compatible, use unicode property `\p{Lu}` that means any uppercase letter in any language:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\p{Lu}+/', function() {
     return rand(0, 9);
}, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
preg_replace_callback('/([A-Z]+)/', function(){
    return mt_rand(0, 9);
},  "X los(2) - XYZ tres");
```

Comment: That will replace with the same random number, unlike the example the OP gave.